# Apparent inconsistency with two different ways of computing a Chern number

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry

Let $W$ be a complex vector bundle of rank $n$, and say it is a sum of line bundles of degree $k_i$: $W = \mathcal{O}(k_1) \oplus \cdots \oplus \mathcal{O}(k_n)$. Then the first Chern number is $c_1(W)= \sum k_i$ by the Whitney sum formula.

We have that $c_1(W) = c_1(\wedge^n W)$ and by the formula $\wedge^n (V_1 \oplus V_2) = \oplus_{p+q=n} (\wedge^p V_1 \otimes \wedge^q V_2)$ we  also have  $\wedge^n W =  \mathcal{O}(k_1) \otimes \cdots \otimes \mathcal{O}(k_n)$. Finally we also have $c_1(E \otimes F) = c_1(E) \mathrm{ rank} F + c_1(F) \mathrm{ rank} E$.

What I am puzzled about is that using this last formulae we obtain:
\begin{align}
c_1(W)&=c_1(\wedge^nW) = c_1(\mathcal{O}(k_1) \otimes \cdots \otimes \mathcal{O}(k_n)) \\
&=k_1(n-1) + c_1(\mathcal{O}(k_2) \otimes \cdots \otimes \mathcal{O}(k_n)) \\
&=k_1(n-1) + k_2 (n-2) + \cdots + k_{n-2}2 +k_{n-1} + k_n
\end{align}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rank of $\mathcal{O}(k_1)$ and $\mathcal{O}(k_2) \otimes \dots \otimes \mathcal{O}(k_n)$ is both one (the tensor product of line bundles is still a line bundle) so the coefficients $\operatorname{rank} F, \operatorname{rank} E$ in the formula for $c_1(E \otimes F)$ are both one.

Comment: Thank you, I knew I was not being very smart